# Sql constraints for "person can only have 1"

Tags: sql

I have a question about writing SQL constraints.

I have two tables:

Person

```
personid (primarykey, int)
name (varchar)
```

Car

```
personid (foreignkey)
brand (varchar)
```

How can I write a constraint that says 'person can only have 1 car'?

Comment: You need to put a unique constraint on `personid` for the car table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you could do it:

Create a unique constraint on Car.PersonId

```
ALTER TABLE Car
ADD UNIQUE (personid)
```

or

Make Car.PersonId the primary key on the table (innately unique)

```
ALTER TABLE Car
ADD PRIMARY KEY (personid)
```

Note that syntax may differ slightly for your RDBMs, you did not specify, but the above is MS sql.

See: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp for different syntaxes on setting up unique constraints across multiple RDBMs

See: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp for the same but on primary keys.

Such a relationship is referred to as a [1 to 1 relationship](http://www.databaseprimer.com/pages/relationship_1to1/)

Answer (score 0):

Check for [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp) and use it on `car.personid`.

Answer (score 0):

Put a [unique constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp) on `car.personid`.